# Does the Inverse-Square law apply with SLA Printing?

Tags: print-quality, sla

I was adjusting the position of our projector to allow for bigger prints to be generated.  I encountered a problem that at larger distances, our prints are not seeming to adhere as desired.

Does the inverse square law of light apply to DLP projectors?

I am aware that the inverse-square law only is 100% applicable when you have a point as your light source.  But I assume close to the same holds constant for other real world light sources.

Unless DLP projectors compensate for distance with their power output. Is this the case?

---

Cross-Post: @ [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342153/inverse-square-law-and-how-it-applies-to-projectors)

Comment: I am currently troubleshooting this.  Running a print right now with the law applied.  So far it seems much more solidly adhered.

Comment: I got pretty decent adhesion with a longer layer times.  Im guessing that this is indeed the case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been [cross-posted at physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342153/inverse-square-law-and-how-it-applies-to-projectors) and is probably more suitable there.

Comment: While this question would probably be *quickly* answered over at Physics.SE, I believe the content is best suited for 3DPrinting.SE. @TomvanderZanden we need to broaden our spectrum of questions regarding other 3D Printer types and draw in more experts. Our site currently has a strong hold on FDM printing to accommodate advanced questions, but I don't feel that we're there yet in other 3D printing types. So, I'm leaving this question open in hopes to encourage more questions about DLP printers.

Comment: @tbm0115 This question has already been cross-posted (verbatim) on Physics.SE and gotten good answers here. Having the same question exist on two different SE's is not good. [See here for a meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). This question could possibly be salvaged by turning it into a more 3D printing specific question. However, allowing substandard questions in a hope to attract more experts is counterproductive. Experts are attracted by interesting, high-quality questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course it does. The same amount of light is being spread across a wider area, so there's less light per area. Once you're past a few 10's of filament diameters, a point source is a highly accurate representation of most light bulbs. Even more so when there's a lens setup that causes the light to go through a point focus.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure if projection software for stereolithographic printers was set up in a way that compensated for this falloff by boosting power.